# WPF AutoCompleteBox binding .Text with Mode=TwoWay not working - .NET4.0

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, autocompletebox

My question is:

I have this `MyAutoCompleteBox`, `ACBoxDest` (it inherits from `AutoCompleteBox` just with a new event `EnterKeyDown` but that should be irrelevant to my question) where the `ItemsSource` is just a list of strings set in the codebehind.

I want to bind the text inside `ACBoxDest` to always be the same as a public field I have in the codebehind called `DestPath`.

Currently, when I change the `DestPath` variable in the codebehind, it doesn't also change the `ACBoxDest` text in the gui.

The .xaml:

```
<MyACBox:MyAutoCompleteBox x:Name="ACBoxDest" FilterMode="StartsWith"
                           Text="{Binding Path=DestPath, Mode=TwoWay}"
                           ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource containerStyle}"
                           Populating="ACBoxDestPopulating"
                           KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                           EnterKeyDown="EnterKeyHandler"
                           GotFocus="ACBoxDestFocused"
                           LostFocus="ACBoxDestUnfocused" />
```

The codebehind:

```
public string DestPath {get;set;}
...
private void Initialize()
{
   DestPath = _DEFAULT_TARGET_PATH;
   if (!ACBoxDest.Text.Equals(DestPath))
      MessageBox.Show("ACBoxDest.Text != DestPath");
}
```

^ For simplicity in explaining debugging, the `MessageBox` pops up every time. This means that the text inside `ACBoxDest` is not equal to `DestPath`, even though they're bound `Mode=TwoWay`. Does anybody know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Swap out your control with an actual `AutoCompleteBox` and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks @Sheridan, I didnt specify this but I did already try that. Same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "DestPath" needs to be a property if you want to use it in Binding.

> The source of the binding can be any public property, including
>   properties of other controls, common language runtime (CLR) objects,
>   XAML elements, ADO.NET DataSets, XML Fragments, and so forth.

More details at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx)

As per comments below:
In order to update your UI when property gets updates, your VM class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and in "set" of DestPath you need to raise property changed event. this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) link has details and sample code.

Comment: Thanks. I almost responded telling you that of course of course I did, but then when I looked closer I realized I left out the {get;set;} part. So that fixed some of the problem. But changes to DestPath still don't change ACBoxDest.Text (aka the MessageBox still pops up)

Comment: Updated my answer above.